# sed extract the end of a string with regex

Tags: regex, sed, escaping, substring, extract

My issue is quiet simple but I think I missed something somewhere,

I want to extract the path of the following string : "rm -rf /tmp/foo /tmp/bar"

I've tried :

```
echo "rm -rf /tmp/foo" | sed 's/rm (-[A-Za-z]* )*\(.*\)/\1/'
```

I expect as a result :

```
/tmp/foo
```

I'm on AIX and I don't have the GNU extended options

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need some security and/or tolerance

```
YourSource \
 | sed 's#^[[:blank:]]*rm\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}-[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)*[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/#/#
        t
        s/^/#/'
```

Assuming:

- there is no `/` before starting path (ex: in a `-e` argument)
- your file FQN start with a `/` (seems it is for `/tmp` folder so it's ok)

  - you can change the first `/#/#` by something like `\([^$[:cntrl:]]-[:blank:]]\)#\2#` depending real need

Added security:

- if the first replacment is not done (no pattern matching), output is the original but with a `#` in front because working with string having `rm -fr` is always a bit dangerous when thing are not working as it should (like filename with a space in this case)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer! I'm looking for matching a real path so it can be just a filename or a real path like /bar/foo/abc/.../...   The idea to add a # if the first replacement is not done is perfect for my case, I was looking for some security. In fact, I'm trying to write a script to execute some command lines and I need to be careful with the rm command. thanks again

Comment: I'm trying to change the first /#/# by something like \([^$[:cntrl:]]-[:blank:]]\)#\2# . Can you please explaine me a lit more how /#/# is working. sed and regex are not my cup of tea. Thanks

Comment: I use another separator than traditionnal `/` and it is `#`  (look char after `s` is a `#`) to avoid escaping any `/` inside pattern (used in path here) so it is equivalent to `\//\//`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the paranthesis.

```
echo "rm -rf /tmp/foo" | sed 's/rm \(-[A-Za-z]* \)*\(.*\)/\2/'
```

In BRE, if you don't escape paranthesis, it would treat `(` , `)` as literal symbols.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "rm -rf /tmp/foo" | sed -r 's/rm (-[A-Za-z]* )*(.*)/\2/'
```

you have two match group, first will match `-rf`,second is `/tmp/foo`

there two way two update your command, 
 remove the first match group
or
 change `\1` to `\2`